# Are these notes (circled)?

Tags: notation, electric-bass-guitar

This is from bass learning book. How are these G, D, G, D in red?  Shouldn’t they be B, A, B, B?  Sorry again, just starting out on electric bass. [image]

Answer (score 4):

Instead of focusing on the second bar, take a look at the first one.

While the first note is a D, as the chord is, the second is clearly **not** an A, but it's a C#.

When you have [capitalized] letters on top of your staff, they most probably indicate the tonic (or the root) of the chord that is going to be played, not the specific note, otherwise the *note to be played by the bass* will be what is followed by the *slash* (if it exists), unless **explicitly** written in the instrument notation.
In your case the bass line *is* written, but if it's not and you see something like `A/C#` it means that the bass should theoretically play the C# note, even when the *actual* chord is A [major]: a more correct chord writing of the above would have `A/C#` written in the second half of the first measure.

In this specific case, the text-written note does *not* indicate the root note of the chord (so it should be [A]), but the basic chord itself: C# is the third of A [major].

Do consider that it *is* possible that a note of the bass line **can** be a note that is **not** part of the overlying harmony: you can have a natural C in the bass, even if the harmony requires a C# (and even a B♭, which is *not* always the same thing).

Comment: _When you have [capitalized] letters on top of your staff, they most probably indicate the (...) root of the chord_ **No!** this example demonstrates exactly the opposite, that the bass line does not need to be limited to the roots of the chords. Slash notation is used **only** when a specific bass note is required.

Comment: @user1079505 - so slash chords ought to abound in this example?

Comment: @user1079505 with "that is going to be played" was intended for the *chord*, not the note, I misplaced the parentheses.

Comment: @Tim no, the example is fine, the bass doesn't have to play the roots when no slash notation is used. On the other hand if slash is used, that's a strong suggestion for playing a specific bass line.

Comment: @user1079505 - so, why wouldn't the 2nd chord be A/C#, and the 3rd G/B, etc?

Comment: @Tim that seems to be taken from a method, and it's probably explaining how to create a bass line when having standard chords (no slash notation) using narrow intervals. Slash notation is usually a way for the composer or arranger to *highlight* an inversion that is important for the harmony, while using normal chords leaves that to the taste and experience of the musician.

Comment: The picture is from Bass Method Book 1 by Ed Friedland. In the second edition, example 42 is on page 20, but in the OP's picture it shows page number 24, so maybe it's a different edition.

Comment: @Tim why as the slash notation when the bass note is given in the staff?  It would be superfluous.

Comment: @phoog explicitly writing a bass line in staff doesn't mean that a slash notation becomes unnecessary: it better explains the voicing intended for the chord and the harmonic concept behind it, and that can be very important for both other instruments playing along with the bass, or when creating a new arrangement.

Comment: @musicamante the purpose of the slash notation is to communicate the note that is supposed to sound in the bass.  The staff notation does that, so the slash notation is unnecessary.  Obviously, your position is also reasonable, but clearly the authors of the text adopted my position.  In this case, the example is very early in the Book 1 of an elementary method.  Perhaps they introduce slash notation later, though when I scanned an electronic copy I didn't see any slash notation, even in the sections "playing off chord symbols" and "using triads to create bass lines" in Book 3.

Answer (score 2):

Those look like chord symbols for the backing track.  The book probably says this the first time that notation is used.

Comment: I think you’re right, the author says ‘notice how the bass is not always playing the root when the chords change.  You can play other notes that belong to the chord.”

Comment: @dlb this score demonstrates exactly that

Comment: Probably it wants to show which alternative tones you can play instead of the root notes.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to read all notes correctly. Look up the bass clef.

Then - like other answers say - the capital letters are chord symbols. Write down all triads of the chords D,G,A and you will find that the tones of these bass line are either the root, third or fifth of these chords (except some quarters that are passing notes.)

Answer (score 1):

Turn back to page 22, and read the explanatory text at the top.  The relevant portion:

> The bass line corresponds directly to **chords** that a guitarist or pianist plays.  They will be written above each measure so that your teacher or a friend can play along with you.  If you examine the bass line, you will see that when the chord symbol says E7, the bass starts the measure with an E; when the chord changes to A7, the bass plays A; etc.  You are playing the *root* of the chord, a very important aspect of functional bass playing.

(Bold and italic text reflect the original.)

In the example you're asking about, the last sentence is no longer true:  Sometimes you play the *third* or *fifth* of the chord (which is another important aspect of functional bass playing).

Comment: Page 22 of what? (I know that Michael Curtis names the book, but helpful to have it here, too.)

Comment: Thanks everyone, just want to mention learning from scratch is very visual so the other notes are a distraction.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here's a picture of the same exercise from the same book (*Bass Method Book 1* by Ed Friedland) that was used by a young student of a music school. The bass teacher has most probably explained about chord symbols, and told the student to add the written bass inversions (the notes on the staff) using slash chord notation, which the student has apparently done:

[image: bass method book lesson with annotations]

I wanted to post this just to show that it's good to have a teacher. :) It's the teacher's job to make sure that the student doesn't miss important things.